# Elixir Postgres view returning empty dataset when testing

Tags: postgresql, testing, view, elixir

I am trying to test a view created in Postgres, but it is returning an empty result set. However, when testing out the view in an Elixir interactive shell, I get back the expected data. Here are the steps I have taken to create and test the view:

1. Create a migration:

```
 def up do
   execute """
     CREATE VIEW example_view AS
     ...
```

2. Create the schema:

```
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "test_view" do
   field(:user_id, :string)
```

3. Test:

```
  describe "example loads" do
   setup [
     :with_example_data
   ]

   test "view" do
     query = from(ev in Schema.ExampleView)
     IO.inspect Repo.all(query)
   end
 end
```

The response back is an empty array `[]`

Is there a setting that I am missing to allow for views to be tested in test?

Comment: Interactive shell by default is started in `:dev` environment, while tests are being run in `:test` environment, with the DB cleaned up every time. Try to query the original table immediately before you are querying the view and see if the data is there.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I queried the original table on the test, and the the data is present. It's just showing an empty array for the view.

Comment: Put a breakpoint into your test with [`IEx.pry/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#pry/0), and examine your DB with some DB explorer, like `psql` or whatever.

Comment: Using pry, the data is available when accessing it without a view. The problem seems to be specifically with the :test environment.

Comment: I am repeating what has already been said but can you confirm that you are doing `psql my_app_test` and _not_ doing `psql my_app_dev` when looking at the DB? The tests use a different database.

Comment: Maybe views are not compatible with https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html I'm not sure but maybe that's worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in one of the comments:

- iex, `mix phx.server`... run on the `:dev` environment and the dev DB
- tests use the `:test` environment and runs on a separate DB

It actually makes a lot of sense because you want your test suite to be reproducible and independent of whatever records that you might create/edit in your dev env.

You can open iex in the `:test` environment to confirm that your query returns the empty array here too:

```sh
MIX_ENV=test iex -S mix
```

What you'll need is to populate your test DB with some known records before querying. There are at least 2 ways to achieve that: fixtures and seeds.

1. Fixtures:

- define some helper functions to create records in `test/support/test_helpers.ex` (typically: takes some `attrs`, adds some defaults and calls some `create_` function from your context)

```
  def foo_fixture(attrs \\ %{}) do
    {:ok, foo} =
      attrs
      |> Enum.into(%{name: "foo", bar: " default bar"})
      |> MyContext.create_foo()

    foo
  end
```

- call them within your `setup` function or test case before querying
- side note: you should use [DataCase](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/testing_contexts.html#the-datacase) for tests involving the DB. With `DataCase`, each test is wrapped in its own transaction and any fixture that you created will be rollback-ed at the end of the test, so tests are isolated and independent from each other.

2. Seeds:

- If you want to include some "long-lasting" records as part of your "default state" (e.g. for a list of countries, categories...), you could define some seeds in `priv/repo/seeds.exs`.
- The file should have been created by the phoenix generator and indicate you how to add seeds (typically use `Repo.insert!/1`)
- By default, mix will run those seeds whenever you run `mix ecto.setup` or `mix ecto.reset` just after your migrations (whatever the env used)
- To apply any changes in `seeds.exs`, you can run the following:

```sh
# reset dev DB
mix ecto.reset
# reset test DB
MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset
```

- If you need some seeds to be environment specific, you can always introduce different seed files (e.g. `dev_seeds.exs`) and modify your `mix.exs` to configure `ecto.setup`.
- Seeds can be very helpful not only for tests but for dev/staging in the early stage of a project, while you are still tinkering a lot with your schema and you are dropping the DB frequently.

I usually find myself using a mix of both approaches.